# R - Calculate totals using a parent-child relation table

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset which contains two tables: one that gives the value of a number of variables at the lowest level, and one that shows all child-parent relations which I should use to calculate the totals.

My data looks something like this:

```
> # table that shows child-parent relation
> ID <- c(5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)
> PARENT_ID <- c(NA, 5, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5, 60, 60, 60, 60)
> df_relation <- data.frame(ID, PARENT_ID)
> df_relation
    ID PARENT_ID
1    5        NA
2   10         5
3   20        10
4   30        10
5   40         5
6   50         5
7   60         5
8   70        60
9   80        60
10  90        60
11 100        60
> # For instance, ID 70 + 80 + 90 + 100 gives the value for ID 60
> 
> # table that contains values at the lowest level
> ID <- c(20, 30, 40, 50, 70, 80, 90, 100)
> VALUE <- c(14, 1, 4329, 98503, 272, 667, 712, 55)
> df_value <- data.frame(ID, VALUE)
> df_value
   ID VALUE
1  20    14
2  30     1
3  40  4329
4  50 98503
5  70   272
6  80   667
7  90   712
8 100    55
> 
> # add values to relation table
> df <- left_join(df_relation, df_value, by = "ID")
> df
    ID PARENT_ID VALUE
1    5        NA    NA
2   10         5    NA
3   20        10    14
4   30        10     1
5   40         5  4329
6   50         5 98503
7   60         5    NA
8   70        60   272
9   80        60   667
10  90        60   712
11 100        60    55
> 
> # compute totals (ID = 5, 10 & 60)
> # ID 60 = 70 + 80 + 90 + 100
> # ID 10 = 20 = 30
> # ID 5 = 10 + 40 + 50 + 60
```

Off course, I can do this manually, but I also have a number of additional tables which have even more child-parent levels. So I would rather have a function which could do the job.
Would anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to use recursion here:

```
sum_children <- function(ID, data)
{
  result <- 0;
  children <- which(data$PARENT_ID == ID)
  if(length(children) == 0) 
    return(data$VALUE[which(data$ID == ID)])
  else 
    for(i in seq_along(children)) 
      result <- result + sum_children(data$ID[children[i]], data)
  return(result)
}
```

This function will take an ID whose child sums you wish to calculate and return the result.

```
sum_children(60, df)
#> [1] 1706
```

It will work to any depth. For example, each node with a value in your example is ultimately descended from ID 5. Therefore the child sum of 5 should be the same as the total of `VALUE`

```
sum(df$VALUE, na.rm = T)
#> [1] 104553

sum_children(5, df)
#> [1] 104553
```

And in fact, you can quickly get the result for all descendants for each ID by doing:

```
df$child_sum <- sapply(df$ID, sum_children, df)

df
#>     ID PARENT_ID VALUE child_sum
#> 1    5        NA    NA    104553
#> 2   10         5    NA        15
#> 3   20        10    14        14
#> 4   30        10     1         1
#> 5   40         5  4329      4329
#> 6   50         5 98503     98503
#> 7   60         5    NA      1706
#> 8   70        60   272       272
#> 9   80        60   667       667
#> 10  90        60   712       712
#> 11 100        60    55        55
```

Comment: This sounds like it would do exactly what I would like to do, thank you! One small aditional question: my original dataset also contains a number of years, and I wish to calculate te totals for each year. How would I incorporate that into your child_sum function?

Comment: @user10781624 you would need to pass the year in as a function parameter, so that the first line reads `sum_children <- function(ID, data, year)`. In the body of the function you would need to change `data$ID == ID` to something like  `data$ID == ID & data$Year == year`, and `data$PARENT_ID == ID` to `data$PARENT_ID == ID & data&Year == year`

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I understood this correctly, but if it's just about to sum up the ID column which have the same PARENT_ID, then it would be:

```
df %>% group_by(PARENT_ID) %>% summarise(TOTALS = sum(ID))
```